# firefox addon repack

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I create a firefox addon using the addon builder
https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/

From there I downloaded the distributable file, but they didnt include an option for setting the addon icon.
I heard that by default it uses icon.png, so I unzipped the xpi file, put the icon in the folder. But when I re-zip it, it always denies the addon.
How can I re-zip without this issue.

Also how can I develop firefox addons in general. 
I am interested in a book that explains everything top to bottom, instead of some very poorly written snippet examples that are scattered across the web.

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack add-ons are signed automatically, simply changing something won't work because the signature becomes invalid. If you need features that the builder doesn't provide you need to [download the SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/builder) and create a package yourself. SDK documentation: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/

**Update**: The "signing" part is outdated, the Add-on SDK no longer signs the add-ons. Still, creating a new package is the way to go here - one might run into all kinds of obscure issues otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repack it as a *zip* file with the zip extension. The install.rdf should be at the root directory of the zip file, i,e. it shouldn't contain a root directory that holds these files.

After repacking as a zip, rename it to xpi. Keep in mind that if you are in Windows, you need to configure it to show the file extensions.

[Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/extensions) contains some useful documentation, but not sure whether it's advanced enough to fit your needs.

Comment: Ive already tried zip, tar, and 7z. All come up as an invalid addon.

Answer (score 0):

Open the addon with an unzip program (dont extract it), and throw inside the icon.png or that ever you want to add, overwrite.

Edit: you can add icon into the package.json... it is editable just after the input for the name of the add on.